# How to fix Error installing RCurl on Mac OS X from source: 'curl/curl.h' file not found

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

Trying to reinstall RCurl from source so it can support sftp (having just installed libssh2 using homebrew):

```
install.packages("RCurl", type = "source")
```

I then get:

```
In file included from base64.c:1:
./Rcurl.h:4:10: fatal error: 'curl/curl.h' file not found
#include <curl/curl.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [base64.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RCurl’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried Googling and looking on StackOverflow and there are plenty of threads on Debian, Linux, Ubuntu and Windows and none on Mac OS X hence this post.

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: Is libcurl installed on your system? Is curl on your path?

Comment: Dear Roland, thanks for your reply, is there a quick way to check on both on the command line? If so, could you tell me please?

Comment: Just do `echo $PATH`.